# Simple PHP MYSQL select statement doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, so I have a simple database with one table, and I have a function which is supposed to get all the rows for that one table:

```
function get_days() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM days'
            . 'ORDER BY idDays';
    $statement = $db ->prepare($query);
    $statement ->execute();
    $the_days = $statement->fetchAll();
    //$statement->closeCursor();
    return $the_days;
    //return $statement;
}
```

I've checked everything else, everything else functions just fine, including the part of my site where I input data into the table, that insert statement works just fine, so I've narrowed it down to this one select statement.

Comment: you don't need a prepared statement, do you?

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM days ORDER BY idDays ASC';

Comment: you have a error in your query i believe as @whoami suggested 
correct query is `'SELECT * FROM days ORDER BY id,Days ASC';`

Comment: Your query is wrong. You can avoid that with proper error checking. Right now your query is: `SELECT * FROM daysORDER BY idDays` because you didn't include a space character.

Comment: @Lambda7 No he doesn't. But it's generaly a good idea to do so anyway. I'm explaining more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230504/bind-param-only-necessary-on-user-inputted-values-or-all/31230713#31230713

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in you SQL syntax. You should do this:

```
function get_days() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM days '
            . 'ORDER BY id';
    $statement = $db ->prepare($query);
    $statement ->execute();
    $the_days = $statement->fetchAll();
    //$statement->closeCursor();
    return $the_days;
    //return $statement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the string concatenation of your query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM days' . 'ORDER BY idDays';
```

This results in: `SELECT * FROM daysORDER BY idDays`

Include a space character instead:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM days' . ' ORDER BY idDays';
```

You can avoid problems like this with proper error handling:

```
try{
    $statement->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

You might also want to remove the spaces in:

```
$db ->prepare($query);
$statement ->execute();
```

So they become:

```
$db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple way to select you can use a  function for it.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM days ORDER BY idDays";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //do  anything
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
```

Comment: This is just a very bad answer. Where do you see `$conn` in his question? Why did you remove the function `get_days()`? Where is your error handing? Why did you remove the Prepared Statement? Where is your explanation of this answer?